# Проблема при чтении из XML файла. Java, Sax parser

Tags: java, sax

У меня есть файл в 17.5 мб, и где-то в середине все ломается ( то есть до этого понятное дело нормально проходит). В общем. main:

```
package main.java.SimanticAnalysis;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimanticAnalysisApplication {
    private static ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();
        parser.parse(new File(
                "/Users/Yaroslav/Desktop/SimaticAnalysis/src/main/resource/MyComments3.xml"), handler);

        int size = 0;
        for (Comment comment: comments){
            size++;
        }
        System.out.print(size);
    }

    private static class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        private Integer score, content_id, element_id, user_id;
        private String text = "", lastElementName;
        private Attributes attributesForCharacters;

        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            // Тут будет логика реакции на начало документа
        }

        @Override
        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            // Тут будет логика реакции на конец документа
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                throws SAXException {
            // Тут будет логика реакции на начало элемента
            lastElementName = qName;
            attributesForCharacters = attributes;
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            // Тут будет логика реакции на конец элемента
            if( score != null && content_id != null && element_id != null && user_id != null &&
                    !text.equals("") ){
                System.out.print("add Comment!");
                comments.add(new Comment(score, content_id, element_id, user_id, text));
                score = null;
                content_id = null;
                element_id = null;
                user_id = null;
                text = "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            String information = new String(ch, start, length);

            System.out.print(lastElementName+" ");
            System.out.print(attributesForCharacters.getValue("columnNumber")+" ");
            System.out.print(information + "\n");

            information = information.replace("\n", "").trim();

            if (!information.isEmpty()) {
                if (lastElementName.equals("value")
                        && attributesForCharacters.getValue("columnNumber").equals("0"))
                    score = Integer.parseInt(information);
                if (lastElementName.equals("value")
                        && attributesForCharacters.getValue("columnNumber").equals("1"))
                    content_id = Integer.parseInt(information);
                if (lastElementName.equals("value")
                        && attributesForCharacters.getValue("columnNumber").equals("2"))
                    element_id = Integer.parseInt(information);
                if (lastElementName.equals("value")
                        && attributesForCharacters.getValue("columnNumber").equals("3"))
                    user_id = Integer.parseInt(information);
                if (lastElementName.equals("value")
                        && attributesForCharacters.getValue("columnNumber").equals("4"))
                    text = text + information;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            // Тут будет логика реакции на пустое пространство внутри элементов (пробелы, переносы строчек и так далее).
        }

    }
}
```

Класс Comment:

```
package main.java.SimanticAnalysis;

public class Comment {
    private Integer score, content_id, element_id, user_id;
    private String text;

    public Comment(int score, int content_id, int element_id, int user_id, String text){
        this.score = score;
        this.content_id = content_id;
        this.element_id = element_id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getScore(){ return  score; }

    public Integer getContent_id(){ return content_id; }

    public Integer getElement_id(){ return element_id; }

    public Integer getUser_id(){ return user_id; }

    public String getText(){ return text; }

}
```

Ошибка в [image: XML]

Что выдает java [image: Run]

то-есть он считывает columnNumber и получает 1, а должен 4... 
В чем может быть проблема?

Ps. Если из кода удалить элементы content_id, element_id и user_id, то он уйдет дальше до 50тыс строчки, но все равно заглохнет.

Comment: А это единственное место в данном XML файле, где присутствует данный текст? Может быть есть ещё одно, невалидное место? Кстати, подобные проблемы с входным XML файлом желательно выяснять при помощи валидации по XSD или DTD https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/validation.html

Comment: Значения атрибутов следует получать в методе `startElement`. Метод `characters` вызывается при разборе текстового содержимого узла. Если узел пуст - он (возможно?) вообще не вызовется. Кроме того, согласно спецификации, `characters` может вызываться несколько раз (обработка текста чанками-кусками) - соответственно, у вас будет несколько раз происходить обработка атрибутов.

Comment: текст ошибки лучше прикреплять текстом, это позволяет копировать и пользоваться поиском

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо! поставил в startElement:
   `attributesForCharacters = attributes.getValue("columnNumber");`
И поменял немного characters и все работает!